# is it safe to redirect to previous page as done in my code ? considering the security measures

Tags: javascript, security, path, decorator

i am trying to redirect user back to the origin page , As variables and scripts is accessible to all in browser , on can manipulate variable (HERE IN MY CASE WR),so considering a security , is it advisable to redirect user as show below code

```
//from submission using ajax
$('#loginform').submit(function (e) {
    var wr;
    e.preventDefault()
   $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'login', //$(this).method
    data: $(this).serializeArray()
 })
 .done(function (response) {
    wr = JSON.stringify(document.referrer)
    //if 'coursedetail in url redirect to the previous page '
    if (wr.includes('coursedetail')) {
        window.location.href = document.referrer;
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect any client-side script to run as you intended. One could configure its browser to ignore your redirection, totally disable JavaScript, etc. Client-side security is not a thing, security is to be considered at the back-end level.

Comment: Thank you for answring , here in my case i am trying to build single page application using django and ajax , with the django as a back end every time i make HttpRequests , it reloads whole page and it makes website slow , how am i supposed to do that with the tools i am  currently using , please brief , your support will be appriciated

Comment: Well this is a totally different question, I invite you to create a new thread and give us more details by giving a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).